# How to output a date range for each quarter of a year in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Thanks to some people on this board I was able to come up with a function that returns a number of date ranges:

```
years = [2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009]

def month_ranges
  years.flat_map { |y|
    12.downto(1).map { |m| Date.new(y,m,1)..Date.new(y,m,-1) }
  }
end

# => 

[
  01 Dec 2013..31 Dec 2013, 
  01 Nov 2013..31 Nov 2013, 
  01 Oct 2013..31 Oct 2013, 
  01 Sep 2013..31 Sep 2013,
  01 Aug 2013..31 Aug 2013,
  ....
]
```

Now, is there a way to return the four **quarters** of a year as well?

So the output will be something like:

```
# => 

[
  01 Oct 2013..31 Dec 2013,
  01 Jul 2013..31 Sep 2013,
  01 Apr 2013..31 Jun 2013,
  01 Jan 2013..31 Mar 2013
]
```

(Note: If a month has 30 or 31 days doesn't really matter in this case.)

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why have you defined years as a function returning an array, instead of just doing `years = [2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009]`?

Comment: Because I am still learning Ruby :-) OK, will adjust it accordingly.

Comment: That's er very good reason.

Comment: What have you tried? "Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)". Your question could be answered using a very similar algorithm. Also, there aren't 31 days in November or September; It's important that your desired output accurately reflect what you need. Potential answerers will code to your spec, right or wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work (based on `month_ranges`, i.e. last quarter comes first):

```
def quarter_ranges
  years.flat_map { |y|
    3.downto(0).map { |q|
      Date.new(y, q * 3 + 1, 1)..Date.new(y, q * 3 + 3, -1)
    }
  }
end
```

Or a bit more verbose and maybe easier to understand:

```
def quarter_ranges
  years.flat_map { |y|
    [
      Date.new(y, 10, 1)..Date.new(y, 12, -1),
      Date.new(y,  7, 1)..Date.new(y,  9, -1),
      Date.new(y,  4, 1)..Date.new(y,  6, -1),
      Date.new(y,  1, 1)..Date.new(y,  3, -1)
    ]
  }
end
```

Comment: I prefer the non-verbose version :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `beginning_of_quarter` and `end_of_quarter` to define quarters.

For example, if I want to group a date_range according to quarters I could do the following:

```
((Date.today - 1.year)..Date.today).group_by(&:beginning_of_quarter)
```

The keys in this case are the beginning of each quarter:

```
((Date.today - 1.year)..Date.today).group_by(&:beginning_of_quarter).keys
=> [Sun, 01 Jul 2012, Mon, 01 Oct 2012, Tue, 01 Jan 2013, Mon, 01 Apr 2013, Mon, 01 Jul 2013]
```

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this:

```
> now = Time.now.beginning_of_month
 => 2013-09-01 00:00:00 +0200
> now..(now + 3.months)
 => 2013-09-01 00:00:00 +0200..2013-12-01 00:00:00 +0100
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like:

```
require 'date'
def quarters(y)
  q = []
  (1..4).each do |s|
    q << (Date.new(y, s * 3 - 1, 1)..Date.new(y, s * 3, -1))
  end
  return q
end
```